# Using Selenium and Python to scrape Morningstar website. Selenium doesn't download the full webpage

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree

url = 'https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xbsp/UGPA3/quote'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
htmlpage = browser.page_source

doc = etree.HTML(htmlpage)
cap = doc.xpath(
    '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/main/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/sal-components/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[7]/div/div[2]/text()')

print(cap)
```

I'm trying to scrape the Market Cap number from the webpage.

I found out after writing the htmlpage variable to a file that the problem is that it's not downloading the whole page. It downloads 2228 KB, while my browser downloads a 2664 KB .html file plus a folder that's not necessary. If I manually save the page with my browser and use its contents as an input to etree.HTML() it works, but I want to automate.

Comment: specify the actual problem and you just want to scrape market cap?

Comment: I need to scrape many values from this page and similar pages, but I'm guessing if I can scrape Market Cap here I can do the others too.

The problem is that the cap variable I print is empty because the xpath I try to find is not among what Selenium downloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    import time

    CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"

    url = 'https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xbsp/UGPA3/quote'
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)

    browser.get(url)

    time.sleep(2)

    # get cap  value from page source and wait for element is present
    cap = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                    '//*[@id="__layout"]/div/div[3]/main/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/sal-components/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[7]/div/div[2]')))
    cap_value = cap.text
    print(cap_value)
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! The only thing needed was to add 'time.sleep(2)'